# Changing text colour on links in lists

Tags: html, css, colors, hyperlink, styling

I'm new to css styling and am wondering if there is a more efficient way to change the colour of the text of links when they are in a list, in my code I am using the same colour for all the links.

```
<h1>Lab Exercises</h1>
<ol class="orderedlist">
  <li><a class="listitem" href="labExercises/ex1">Lab 1</a></li>
  <li><a class="listitem" href="labExercises/ex2">Lab 2</a></li>
  <li><a class="listitem" href="labExercises/ex3">Lab 3</a></li>
  <li><a class="listitem" href="labExercises/ex4">Lab 4</a></li>
  <li><a class="listitem" href="labExercises/ex5">Lab 5</a></li>
  <li><a class="listitem" href="labExercises/ex6">Lab 6</a></li>
  <li><a class="listitem" href="labExercises/ex7">Lab 7</a></li>
  <li><a class="listitem" href="labExercises/ex8">Lab 8</a></li>
</ol>
```

CSS

```
.listitem { color: orchid}
.orderedlist { color: fuchsia }
```

Comment: what worng of what you did?I thing using `class` as you did is good way

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
li a {
    color: orchid;
}
```

This way you don't have to add `class="listitem"` in every row.

I think that this code answers your question: 
"a more efficient way to change the colour of the text of links when they are in a list".

Comment: You can be more specific to only this `ol`: `.orderedlist li a{}`

Comment: @לבנימלכה I think he meant in his question that he wants to avoid adding the "orderlist" class in every "li". אחותי

Comment: I thing to avoid use class to `a` ... ואני אחות לא אח

Comment: "a more efficient way to change the color of the text of links when they are in a list" it looks like he wants that if more links are added to the "li" they will get the color style (without him adding the class name as a more efficient way). ותיקנתי

Comment: yea thats exactly it, i didn't want to add a class name for each item in the list. sorry boys i was a lil tipsy when writing the post

Answer (score 2):

css

```
 .orderedlist,
 .orderedlist a,
 .listitem { 
      color: orchid;
      text-decoration:none;
  }

 .orderedlist a:hover,
 .listitem:hover { 
     color: fuchsia;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have a global level links and a different colored links within listitems, by doing this you can or don't have to add `class="listitem"` to every links in a list.

```css
a {
  color: #007bff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover {
  color: #0056b3;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.orderedlist,
.orderedlist a,
.listitem { color: orchid }

.orderedlist a:hover,
.listitem:hover { color: fuchsia }
```

```html
<h1>Lab Exercises</h1>
<a href="#">Other links</a>
<ol class="orderedlist">
  <li><a class="listitem" href="labExercises/ex1">Lab 1</a></li>
  <li><a class="listitem" href="labExercises/ex2">Lab 2</a></li>
  <li><a class="listitem" href="labExercises/ex3">Lab 3</a></li>
  <li><a class="listitem" href="labExercises/ex4">Lab 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="labExercises/ex5">Lab 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="labExercises/ex6">Lab 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="labExercises/ex7">Lab 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="labExercises/ex8">Lab 8</a></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.orderedlist li a {color: orchid }
```

```html
<h2>list</h2>
<ol class="orderedlist">
  <li><a href="labExercises/ex1">Lab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="labExercises/ex2">Lab 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="labExercises/ex3">Lab 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="labExercises/ex4">Lab 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="labExercises/ex5">Lab 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="labExercises/ex6">Lab 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="labExercises/ex7">Lab 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="labExercises/ex8">Lab 8</a></li>
</ol>
```